# Pause Menu In SpriteKit - Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, pause

I have read some other questions asked about pause menus in swift but I cant seem to get it to work. I know that I have to use layers but I don't know what to do with the layers.

So far I have

```
let pauseLayer = SKNode()
let gameLayer = SKNode()


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    self.addChild(gameLayer)
}
```

With this, I have these two functions:

```
func pauseButtonSetup()
{
    gameLayer.isPaused = true
    self.physicsWorld.speed = 0;
    self.addChild(pauseLayer)
}

func unpauseButtonSetup()
{
    pauseLayer.removeFromParent()
    self.physicsWorld.speed = 1;
    gameLayer.isPaused = false
}
```

Basically, I would like to tap the pause button and then a pause menu comes up. But everything in the background stops and can be resumed. My game includes swiping and actions to move the enemies. I don't know what to do with the two layers I have created.

Sorry as I am still a beginner to swift

Comment: imo i would make paise screen a SkScene then use 'view!.presentScene'. just make sure you have a reference somewhere to your gamescene so it doesnt deinit

Comment: The code you have posted here should work to do a pause like you have requested.  Assuming you have setup the pause layer correctly and these functions are called when the buttons are tapped.